# Expansion tanks

Tags: plumbing

Will an expansion tank maintain house pressure on cold water lines in homes? Water pressure in system is 60 lbs removed all galvanized piping, replaced all mains with 3/4" copper.  When using hose bibs which are new pressure drops on system to 11 lbs.

Comment: What is the source of water? Well, municipal system...?

Answer (score 1):

Expansion tanks absorb excess pressure, they don't maintain system pressures.

I think what you're looking for is a pressure tank. While similar in design to an expansion tank, a pressure tank serves a different purpose and is typically much larger.

If installed properly, a pressure tank can help keep system pressure more stable during high demand.  However, they do have limitations. Specifically if the high demand is prolonged, the tanks ability to maintain normal pressures will be reduced or lost completely.

Once the demand is reduced, the tank will refill, and the pressure will again be stabilized.

Comment: This is true codewise, but technically speaking an expansion tank is a tiny pressure tank designed for hot water. There's no functional mechanical difference; they're both just air-bladder springs.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer An expansion tank will be charged so that it only fills when the pressure in the system increases, e.g. when the water is heated. A pressure tank is charged below the supply pressure, so that it is normally full of water. So while they are similar in design, they serve separate functions.

Comment: That's not entirely correct either. Both types of tanks will always have some water in them. The difference is the ratio of air to water at normal operating pressure.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer The only way you could use an expansion tank as a pressure tank, is if you undercharged it.  And even then; due to it's size, it's usefulness would be limited. You can argue all day that they have some similarities, but in the end they serve different purposes.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer You can drive a nail with a wrench, but that doesn't make it the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Neither an expansion nor a pressure tank (*which are, fundamentally, the same thing, in different sizes, at different precharge levels - more like driving a nail with a sledgehammer than a wrench*) will solve the root problem here unless you only use your hose for very short periods.

Having apparently cleaned up all the old restrictions in the piping, you now have a free and clear path from whatever the source is (as yet unanswered) and the hose bib.

The source is, in some way, for some reason, restricted. Bad valve, small pipe, corroded pipe, small corroded pipe, debris in valve or pipe, undersized water meter, inadequate well pump...can't really isolate a reason as you have not supplied enough data.

So the hose bib takes water faster than the source can supply, until the pressure drops to 11 PSI. If you add a pressure tank, or several in parallel, you can prolong the amount of time (or water) until that happens, but after sufficient time or water use, you will be back at 11 PSI unless the source is improved. If you only use your hose in short bursts, this might be soluble with pressure tanks. If you use it in a more prolonged fashion, you either need to improve the water source, or restrict the supply to the hose bibs in order to maintain more pressure on the house side of the supply.